# syntax error with update statment

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know where is the error in this syntax

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET question='$question', answer='$answer', name='$nwbad' WHERE id='$id'";
```

I doesn't work and after I've printed it

> UPDATE social SET question='اختار الله شبه الجزيره العربيه مهدا الرساله الاسلام', answer='لتكون بعيد عن الصراعات', name='Function Wasn't Added , Updated by: احمد نزار' WHERE id='1' or

What is or?!
And it sometimes shows me that the error at " WHERE id='1' "

Comment: The parameter values are only encapsulted with single quotes, the data "Function wasn't added" has a single quote, thus breaking the sql. As @Harshit noted, use prepared statements / PDO to avoid these sorts of problems and more besides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be from this line

```
'Function Wasn't Added
```

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `prepared statments` to avoid this error.

Comment: It retirved from the database and mixed with other data
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TheName))
{
$arr = array($row['name'], ", " , "Updated by: ", $name);
$nwbad = join(" ", $arr);
}`
row['name'] = Function Wasn't Added

Answer (score 0):

Try this at php side after you are fetching data from database.

$your_string = "Function Wasn't Added.";

echo str_replace(" ' ", " ", $your_string);

NOTE : it will remove all single quotes

You can use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Removing single quotes is not the solution but save it with quotes.

Comment: Then use this function mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the strings before adding them to your SQL query:

```
UPDATE social
SET question='اختار الله شبه الجزيره العربيه مهدا الرساله الاسلام', 
answer='لتكون بعيد عن الصراعات',
name='Function Wasn''t Added , Updated by: احمد نزار'
WHERE id='1'
```

That should work, assuming that updated by is part of your string and not a column in your database.

See this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php